# Flutter ListView на весь экран

Tags: listview, flutter

Подскажите как развернуть на весь экран listView

```
class OrderTestWidget extends StatelessWidget { 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          AppLocalizations.of(context).ordertestwidgetTitle,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: AppColors.secondaryText,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            fontSize: 21,
          ),
        ),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 163, 238),
      ),
      body: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0),
        ),
        child: Column(

          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [

            Container(
              width: 363,
              height: 1000,
              child:  ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 15,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                 return Card (
                 child: Group84ItemWidget(),
                 );
               },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так можно:

```
Container(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 15,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Card(
        child: Group84ItemWidget(),
      );
    },
  ),
),
```

---

[MediaQuery](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html) позволяет вытащить некоторые данные из текшего виждета в дереве виджетов.

[Пример как можно использовать MediaQuery в разных задачах.](https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-guide-to-using-screensize-in-flutter-a-more-readable-approach-901e82556195)

Comment: Это сработало! Спасибо.

Comment: @ДенисАкулов, если вам подошел ответ, примите его.

Comment: за пример спасибо

Comment: @ДенисАкулов всегда пожалуйста, если будут вопросы спрашивайте!